# Is mysqli command also avaible for use in mssql server?

Tags: php, sql-server, mysqli

I still haven't tried using mysqli, because I want to know first if it can be used using mssql server because I'm still planning to buy a license of mssql server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mysqli is specific to MySQL. If you want access to MSSQL, I'd recommend you use PDO, a PHP function set/statement which can generically access various database types using drivers for each type. To connect to a MSSQL database using PDO, you first need SQLSRV, the driver, which you can download from Microsoft [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098). To connect, you would use the following:

```
$handle = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server;Database=$database", $username, $password);
```

To query:

```
$queryRef = $handle->query($query);
```

To read results, declaring `$results` as a two-dimensional associative array, the first being the result number, the second being the column name:

```
$results = $queryRef->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

So `$results[3]['id']` would be the value of the column 'id' of the third result.

You can find more examples on the PHP documentation page for PDO [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). The great thing about PDO is that you can use the same code for different databases, you just need to change the driver, and possibly the queries.

Comment: Correct answer also, but i already marked correct answer earlier. thank you for more details

Answer (score 4):

PHP does have an implementation of MSSQL, however it's not "object-oriented" in the way that mysqli is.

In addition, the SQL syntax does vary slightly between MSSQL and MySQL in specific circumstances such as when limiting the number of results:

```
MySQL:
  SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 100
MSSQL:
  SELECT TOP 100 * FROM table
```

I'd recommend using PDO instead of mysqli, as PDO supports both MySQL and MSSQL.

Answer (score 3):

No, mysqli is for MySql.
See [Mysqli documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php).