# correct mssql connection string in php

Tags: php, sql-server

Perhaps this is the connection string to connect to an sql server

```
<?php
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "your_name";
$myPass = "your_password";
$myDB = "examples";
?>

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
```

but i do not know what to input in the $myServer, $myUser and $myPass
if I wanna use windows authentication

This is my Server details kindly help me please
Microsoft SQL Enterprise Manager
Microsoft Corporation
Version: 8.0

Comment: check manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Answer (score 2):

If you have PHP 5.3 or later, you can no longer use the ms_sql extension, according to the [PHP documentation page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php). I'm not sure of the extent of that, but you may want to consider using PDO instead. It allows for a generic way to access various database types, including MSSQL. To connect to a MSSQL database using PDO, you first need SQLSRV, the driver, which you can download from Microsoft [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098). To connect, you would use the following:

```
$handle = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server;Database=$database", $username, $password);
```

Above, and to answer the main part of your question, `$server` is probably `localhost`, and your username and password can be accessed and changed from within the Microsoft SQL Server access panel. I believe you can use `"sa"` for `$username` and `""` for `$password`. For `$database`, just put in the name of the database you want to connect to.

To query:

```
$queryRef = $handle->query($query);
```

To read results, declaring `$results` as a two-dimensional associative array, the first being the result number, the second being the column name:

```
$results = $queryRef->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

So `$results[3]['id']` would be the value of the column 'id' of the third result.

You can find more examples on the PHP documentation page for PDO [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Much of this was taken from my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181578/is-mysqli-command-also-avaible-for-use-in-mssql-server/17181871#17181871).

Answer (score 0):

Your server is usually localhost, and your username and password could be changed and viewed by following this tutorial:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/29/sql-server-change-password-of-sa-login-using-management-studio/